# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory()

Tags: jackson, rcp, nosuchmethoderror

I'm facing an issue while developping a plugin project. When i run the product, i got this :

java.lang.**NoSuchMethodError**: **org.codehaus.jackson**.map.ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory()

The two plugins i'm using for parsing Json with Jackson are :

**org.codehaus.jackson.core 1.6.0**

**org.codehaus.jackson.mapper 1.6.0**

I don't use Maven, all dependecnies are available from the Manifest.

I know it's reccurent problem, but i can't find the solution.

Could someone help please?!

Ismail

Comment: `ObjectMapper` class in this version does not contain `getTypeFactory` method. Could you upgrade Jackson library to the newest version?

Comment: The jackson lib is the newest. I've solved my problem my creating a  Plug-in from Existing Jar Archives, where i've putted all the required Jar's. Then i added the plugin to my dependecie tab. After that the compilation was good and i've got my result.